# How can I pass username/password as an encrypted via SoapClient in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, soap

I am using SoapClient to call a wsdl web-service, and it is working fine, but I have to send the username and password as an encrypted text not as a plane text (my web service is using HTTPS) , any idea guys?

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://my-server/ws/student_api.php?wsdl", array('login'=> "test@test.ac.ae",'password'       => "123456"));
$client->__soapCall("getStudentList", array("std_id1"));
```

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php ?

Comment: Since your web service is using HTTPS already, anything including usernames and passwords is already encrypted. What more do you need?

Comment: I pass the username/password as parameters to the SoapClient, they will be encrypted while the webservice is HTTPS?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I got this report from AlienVault 
AlienVault NIDS: "ET POLICY
Outgoing Basic Auth Base64 HTTP
Password detected unencrypted"

Comment: Maybe you should capture the traffic using wireshark or tcpdump and verify that the HTTP headers for basic auth are actually sent over the encrypted connection. I see no reason this should not be the case.